# Why can't an identifier begin with a digit in java

Tags: java

I can not think anything other than "string of digits would be a valid identifier as well as a valid number."

Is there any other explanation other than this one?

Comment: Why is `for` used to designate a loop is Java? It's just a design decision.

Comment: *"Is there any other explanation other than this one"* - if you can think of one reason it's a bad idea, why would you need another?

Comment: Mainly because to do so would make the language incredibly bug-prone.  A harmless literal could be turned into a variable reference by a edit elsewhere in the program.

Answer (score 12):

Because that would make telling number literals from symbols names a serious PITA.

For example with a digit being valid for the first character a variables of the names `0xdeadbeef` or `0xc00lcafe` were valid. But that could be interpreted as a hexadecimal number as well. By limiting the first character of a symbol to be a non-digit, ambiguities of that kind are avoided.

Answer (score 9):

If it could then this assignment would be possible

```
int 33 = 44; // oh oh
```

then how would the JVM distinguish between a numeric literal and a variable?

Comment: Addition: if you do `return 33 + 1` afterwards - should it return `34` or `45` ?

Comment: I remember a FORTRAN compiler (on an old, old minicomputer) that allowed the statement `DO 10 1 = 0 TO 10` (equivalent to `for (1 = 0; 1 <= 10; 1++)`).  When we looked at the disassembled code it really was assigning 0 to the literal for `1`.  (Obviously this was a compiler bug, but such bugs were not unusual in that time frame.)  The error was hard to find because `1` and `I` look remarkably similar on a Teletype printout.

Comment: A less strict rule like "Identifier names must have at least one alphabet character" can avoid situations like this. So your example doesn't demonstrate why an identifier must not begin with a digit.

Comment: There's a difference between "why can't an identifier consist of only digits" and "... begin with a digit", which was asked. From a tokenizer or parser point of view, a rule like `an identifier is any sequence of (alphabet|underscore|digit) which is not a reserved word or a number literal [e.g. 0x0]` would be simple. Even in languages which have [contextual keywords](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/contextual-keywords) [which are not reserved words], this would be a relatively simple exercise. Thus, your answer is at best a question, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

It's to keep the rules simple for the compiler as well as for the programmer.

An identifier could be defined as any alphanumeric sequence that can not be interpreted as a number, but you would get into situations where the compiler would interpret the code differently from what you expect.

Example:

```
double 1e = 9;
double x = 1e-4;
```

The result in `x` would not be `5` but `0.0001` as `1e-4` is a number in scientific notation and not interpreted as `1e` minus `4`.

Answer (score 2):

This is done in Java and in many other languages so that a parser could classify a terminal symbol uniquely regardless of its surrounding context. Technically, it is entirely possible to allow identifiers that look like numbers or even like keywords: for example, it is possible to write a parser that lifts the restriction on identifiers, allowing you to write something like this:

```
int 123 = 321; // 123 is an identifier in this imaginary compiler
```

The compiler knows enough to "understand" that whatever comes after the type name must be a variable name, so `123` is an identifier, and so it *could* treat this as a valid declaration. However, this would create more ambiguities down the road, because `123` becomes in invalid number "shadowed" by your new "identifier".

In the end, the rule works both ways: it helps compiler designers write simpler compilers, and it also helps programmers write readable code.

Note that [there were attempts in the past](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_68) to build compilers that are not particularly picky about names of identifiers - for example

```
int a real int = 3
```

would declare an identifier with spaces (i.e. `"a real int"` is a single identifier). This did not help readability, though, so modern compilers abandoned the trend.